# SAS dsn to SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sas

I was given below instruction by IT team to connect SAS to a SQL server db.

```
libname aa   sqlsvr dsn=dms   user=xx pass='yy' owner=dbo readbuff=30000;
libname aa slibref=aa server=host1 port
```

When I run this, I get:

```
ERROR: The SQLSVR engine cannot be found.
ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.
ERROR: Attempt to connect to server host1 failed.
ERROR: A communication subsystem partner link setup request failure has occurred.
ERROR: Cannot find TCP service 'host1'.
ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.
```

I tried setting up an ODBC connection using host1 as server name, but it says Server does not exist.

What did I do wrong

Comment: Can you go to your computers ODBC connection and test that the DBMS is connected and working?

Comment: It may be that your installation is not licensed for `SAS/ACCESS to SQL Server` or the component is licensed but not installed for the SAS session you are running.  You might have `SAS/ACCESS to ODBC` installed, can you show the code you tried ?

Comment: Why do you have two different libname statements for the same libref, AA.  Which one are you trying to use?  Or are you trying to run one in a remote (SAS/Connect) session and one in the local session to connect to the libref defined in the remote session?

Comment: Try syntax like: `libname My_sql_lib oledb provider=sqloledb  properties=("User ID"=&user_name. Password=&Pw. "data source"=&sqlserver_name. "initial catalog"=&database.)´

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that you haven't set up `sqlsvr` as a DSN in windows yet.

From the `Start` menu, find your ODBC Data Source Administrator menu item.  This differs depending on what version of windows you are running, but there's a good chance you can just click `Start` and type 'odbc' and it will show up. You will most likely want the 64-bit version of the ODBC Administrator, if you're having troubles you can try the 32-bit version.

Once open, go to System DSN, click on Add, Choose the SQL Server driver from the list, and fill out the rest of the details in the wizard.  At the end of the wizard you will have the option to test the configuration.  You must be able to connect successfully with this connection prior to being able to use the `dsn=` statement in SAS.  Once the connection is successfully setup, the `dsn=` statement should work fine.

Your second statement with `host1` and `port` is not a connection to SQL server, as SQL server doesn't use ports in their ODBC connection specifications.  It also looks incomplete as you have it typed there so you may want to double check the code you were provided with.